# C# Windows Forms Application Input String Was Not in a Correct Format When Inserting Dollar Amounts

Tags: c#, sql

I keep getting this error "Input string was not in a correct format" when I'm trying to insert a record with dollar amounts into SQL DB.

I am using C#, Windows Forms Application. In my form, I have a textbox named "quote1". In the DB table, I have a column named "quoteAmount1" DataType "Decimal(8,2) Allow Nulls.

I'm inputting 1300.00 in the textbox then using the following parameter for that textbox to insert into the table:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@quoteAmount1", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(quote1.Text);
```

Can someone let me know if this is, in fact, the wrong format?
Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Does the textbox contain `1300.00`, or `$1300.00`?

Comment: What is the value of `quote1.Text`? Is there a dollar *(or any other nun numerical)* character?

Comment: Also, is the decimal separator of your UiCulture `.` or something else?

Comment: The value of the textbox is 1300.00 with no $ sign and . is the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the actual problem. The parameter was correct. I had 2 additional textboxes for dollar amounts that were null and that is what caused the issue. I had to write an if/else statement to catch the null and use DbNull.Value for those that were left blank.